# Edittext scrolls parent ScrollView to the bottom when I past long text in it

Tags: android

I have a large layout inside a `ScrollView`. There are a few `EditTexts` Which have `maxHeight` set to `100dp`.
The problem is when I copy and past a long text into my `EditText` the height of it does not increase from `maxHeight` (which is normal), but the parent `ScrollView` scrolls to the end. It seems that `ScrollView` does not understand the `maxHeight` attribute of the `EditText` and behaves like there is no `maxHeight` and `EditText` has increased its height to wrap the content of the pasted long text.
It seems this issue is fixed on Android 7+, but on older versions this problem exists.

There is nothing interesting in my layout so I will not put it here. It is just a `ScrollView` which has a `vertical LinearLayout` inside, and `LinearLayout` has a bunch of views and a few `EditTexts` like the following:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/layout_free_text_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/section_background"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/section_text_size"
            android:hint="@string/hint_free_text"/>
```

I have tried to add different attributes to `EditText`, like `maxLine` etc. seems nothing solves the issue. I googled a lot, but there is nothing even similar to this issue anywhere. Can anybody suggest me a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this `android:lines="2"` it also makes you can scroll the EditText